# BizTalk sequential file name

Tags: biztalk

I need to have the file in send port (type File) with sequential number. The format should be i.e. Order_%OrderId%_%Sequence%.xml. Sequnce will be from 1 to ... Only solution I can see is to create table in database which will contain last number for each sequence, in orchestration I'll get the number, concatenate it with the prefix string and store it into variable which I'll use as macro in the send port. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right.
Here is where this solution is discussed in greater details:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/SendHandlerMacro.aspx

There is also a slightly different approach recommended here:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=31802198&threadid=31802196

Comment: (second link is dead)